# Google maps API MapView only shows grid

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying the HelloGoogleMaps project from [this official google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview?hl=es), and I get the applicaiton running just fine, 'cept the map isn't showing; instead you can see a grid without any data. Doing some research I found that the API key could be malfunctioning; I must have done something wrong. But I dont know what it could be, as I followed the instructions given in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/554834020247/apiui/credential?authuser=0). Here's what I did to get the key:

1. I clicked on Create New Key
2. I clicked on Android Key
3. I discovered the SHA1 fingerprint of my developer certificate using the following command:

   keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Viktor.android\debug.keystore
4. I copied the SHA1 certificate and pasted it as the example shows:
   45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example
5. I got the key and placed it in res/layout/main.xml

I did make a OAuth 2.0 Client just in case, and also activated the following APIs in Google Developer's console:
 Google Maps Android API v2, Google Maps Coordinate API, Google Maps Geolocation API, Google Maps JavaScript API v3, Google Maps Tracks API. 
Maybe there is some conflict? Maybe its something version related?

The minimun sdk is API 10 Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread.
The target sdk is API 21 Android 4.x (L Preview), and selected Google APIs 10 to compile it.
There is a mess with the versioning, and all tutorials and solutions I find are not updated, even google tutorials refer to old versions. 
 Anyone can point me in the right direction?

**SOLUTION**
Emulators won't work, as they dont have a GPS or anything, so the best thing is to use a real android device. I tried the answer below, with the genymotion thing and got no result.

Comment: did you just ignore the big bold text at the top that says the `v1` Google Maps API is `Deprecated`?

Comment: try using google map in a fragment. this is a great and detailed tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/. hope this helps

Comment: API v1 is deprecated. Try going over the steps mentioned in google site for api v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: @tyczj I didnt know I was using version 1.

Comment: @Víctor so you didnt read the big bold text then on that page you linked?

Comment: @tyczj I guess I messed up.

Comment: @GuyS Hey man! Thankyou for your comment, I followed the steps mentioned in that tutorial but when I run the application it stops working and forces you to close it. Have you got any idea of whats going on? I started a fresh project and everything

Answer (score 1):

Inbuilt google Emulator will not support google map. Try installing Genymotion emulator and try again.
Also API v1 is deprecated. Try going over the steps mentioned in google site for api v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: Hey, thankyou for your answer, I followed the steps mentioned and cant seem to get it working. This time, the application stops working and forces you to close it. I followed all steps, did all the referencing, etc. Any idea? PS: I started a new project and everything

Comment: Post your code and manifest.. Are you getting an exception, if yes paste the logs too...